# How to plot arrow linestyle using GeoPlot sankey?

Tags: python, geopandas, polyline-creation, flow-map

I am plotting line directions from the US to other countries on a map. I have both geo points of originators and destinations. I use gploy.sankey, however, I am unable to add arrows at the end of the line to indicate the directions. Gplt linestyle includes only dashes and lines, can not recognise '->'. Can anyone help, please?

[image: Transactions go out of the US]

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot as gplt
import geoplot.crs as gcrs
import mapclassify as mc
scheme = mc.UserDefined(map_network_USA['amount_transactions'], bins=[500, 1000, 2000, 3000])
ax = gplt.sankey(map_network_USA, projection=gcrs.WebMercator(),
                      hue='amount_transactions', scheme=scheme, cmap='Oranges', legend=True,
     legend_kwargs={'loc': 'lower left', 'fontsize':15},
     legend_labels=['< $500 million','$500-1,000 million', '$1,000-2,000 million', '$2,000-3,000 million','>$3,000 million'],figsize=(10,15))
gplt.polyplot(world, ax=ax, facecolor='lightgray', edgecolor='white')
plt.title("Sum of ST Originator in the US between 2000 and 2017",fontsize=20)
plt.linestyle='->'
plt.show()
```